# Find strings and add html tags to the beginning and end

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to add html tags (like `<h2>` and `</h2>`) to the beginning and end of a string that is shorter than 100 characters?

For example the string is:

`My name is John`

And as a result we should get: `<h2>My name is John</h2>`

I know how to find strings shorter than 100 characters

```
^.{0,150}$
```

But I can't figure out how to add tags `<h2>` and `</h2>` to the beginning and end of this line.

Comment: Which programming language are you trying to do it in?

Comment: `^.{0,150}$` => `<h2>$&</h2>`

Comment: @amirhossein-nazary in Notepad++